# How to plot this in maple?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maple

Consider this function:  $f(x,y)=xy$ . How to plot the contour of this function and $x^2+y^2=1$ in a plane. I'm not familiar with maple coding but I need the code or at least some instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Is your question "How do I plot the function?"  or "How do I plot the function using Maple?"  If the former, please edit your question to make this more clear, and add some details (e.g. what do you know about contour plots?  what are you studying?  etc).  If the latter, please consult the Maple documentation, or whatever support forums Maplesoft has for helping with their software---Math SE is not a tech support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear to me what you mean.

```
with(plots): with(plottools,circle):
```

Perhaps something like this?

```
display(contourplot(x*y, x=-1..1, y=-1..1,
                    contours=21, grid=[101,101],
                    coloring=["SteelBlue","Gold"],
                    filledregions=true),
        circle([0,0], 1, thickness=2),
        axes=box, scaling=constrained);
```

[image]

Or perhaps like this?

```
display(contourplot(x*y, x=-1..1, y=-sqrt(1-x^2)..sqrt(1-x^2),
                    contours=21, grid=[151,101],
                    coloring=["SteelBlue","Gold"],
                    filledregions=true),
        circle([0,0], 1, thickness=2));
```

[image]

Of course, you can change various options to adjust the shading, resolution, ranges, etc. See the Help page for topic,
[plot,options](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=plot/options)
which is also available in your Maple itself.